# iOS side menu library with left, right and bottom transitions

Tags: ios, user-interface, transition

In my iOS App, I need a side menu with left, right and bottom transitions.

I know about `PPRevealSideViewController`.

Do you know any alternative?

Comment: Look up "sliding menus" on github with the objective-C language tag

Answer (score 0):

I implemented one of these, might be helpful.

https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

Comment: there are no bottom transitions

Answer (score 0):

Found one that can be used with storyboards. But it's quite specific.
[DDSlidingPanels](https://github.com/deem0n/DDSlidingPanels)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [APMultiMenu](https://github.com/aadeshp/APMultiMenu). I've used it and it's simple to use and follow